# Same but why working differently?

Tags: c

We know that parameter receives arguments, that is we are assigning arguments to parameters. If that is, why does this statement `int b[5]=a;` generating an error called invalid initializer and `func(a);` is alright?

```
#include<stdio.h>

void func(int b[5]);

int main(void)
{
    int a[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int b[5]=a;
    func(a);
    return 0;
}

void func(int b[5])
{

}
```

Answer (score 4):

In C, an array decays to a pointer to the first element of the array in the context in which you are using it.

```
int b[5] = a;
```

is equivalent to:

```
int b[5] = &a[0];
```

A pointer to `int` cannot be used to initialize an array of `int`s.

To set the elements of `b` to be the same as the elements of `a`, you have the following options.

1. Initialize `b` a bit differently.

   ```
   int b[5] = {a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4]};
   ```
2. Use `memcpy`.

   ```
   int b[5];
   memcpy(b, a, sizeof(a));
   ```
3. Copy the elements of `a` one by one.

   ```
   int b[5];
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i )
      b[i] = a[i];
   ```

My personal preference would be to use `memcpy`.

Answer (score 3):

> Why does this statement `int b[5]=a;` generating an error called invalid initializer

You are doing two things:

- Define an array `b` of 5 integers.
- Initialize array `b` to array `a`. You can not do this in C. Specifically that statement never initializes `b[0]` to `a[0]`, `b[1]` to `a[1]`, etc. as you would expect. To do so, you would need `memcpy( b, a, sizeof( b ) )`.

> `void * memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );`

Copies the values of num bytes from the location pointed to by source directly to the memory block pointed to by destination.

> `void func(int b[5])`

This function simply takes an array as a parameter - there is no array assignment here.

You can, actually should, write it as (the array size is not needed):

```
void func(int b[])
```

Comment: How does parameter receives the array without assignment where i am sending the base address of the array?

Comment: That's how passing array to function works. When you pass the array name to a function, you are actually parsing the address of the first element of the array to it. Inside the array, you can access/modify any element of that array directly.

Comment: @artm: Nitpicking: One never passes the *name* of a variable. Names are synonyms for variables used by programmers, they do not exist in the code that runs. In cases like your comment, one should simply phrase "*When you pass the array to a function ...*"

Comment: `void func(int b[])` in fact is exactly the same as `void func(int * b)`.